# Validation error while uploading app into marketplace

Tags: html, manifest, mozilla, firefox-os, marketplace

I was submitting my first app (Packaged) into market place. But while uploading the zipped file, they are returning to me and displaying this error message:

> Your app failed validation with 1 error.
>
> Could not decode the webapp manifest file.

Why this is happening? anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the zip in the app validator?  Try it first: https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/validator
Also make sure your manifest.webapp is not nested in any directory.